# How can I monitor my pods running on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, devops

Is it possible to monitor or to get mails alerts while a pod in down? How to set the alert?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it possible you have to setup [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io) with [Alertmanager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/alertmanager).

I recommend using [prometheus-operato](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator) as an easier way to start with monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want to use open source apps or you want to use paid software for monitoring and alerting.

As @FL3SH advised most used software to monitor and sending alerts is `Prometheus` and `Alertmanager`. This solution have many tutorials online "*how to*", for example [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-prometheus-grafana-and-alertmanager-monitoring-stack-on-digitalocean-kubernetes#conclusion).

However there are many other paid software to monitor your `cluster/pods`, alert you, create history diagrams etc. (like datadog, sysdig, Dynatrace) or mixed solutions (like Prometheus and Grafana, cAdvisor, Kibana, etc.) For more information you can check [this article](https://medium.com/containerum/4-tools-to-monitor-your-kubernetes-cluster-efficiently-ceaf62818eea).

Please note that each cloud provider offers some specific monitoring features.